# Error message having no message . and data is not being updated

Tags: java, cloudboost

When executing the below code I get the following in my log

> 05-02 02:19:34.175 8796-8810/com.example.nitikamehta.testing
>   I/System.out: io.cloudboost.CloudException

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CloudApp.init("vuwzaiqgwytr ", "cf358f99-1bbd-4ccc-9a4e-3370b169a50f");
    myAsyncTask mTask = new myAsyncTask();
    mTask.execute("abc", "10", "Hello world");
}


private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    String mTAG = "myAsyncTask";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        CloudObject obj = new CloudObject("users");
        try {
            obj.set("name", "navneet");
            Log.d("here", "also");

        } catch (CloudException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            obj.save(new CloudObjectCallback() {
                         @Override
                         public void done(CloudObject x,CloudException t) {
                             if (x != null) {
                                 Log.d("first", "added");
                             }
                             if (t != null) {
                                  System.out.println(""+t);
                             }

                         }

                     }
            );
        } catch (CloudException e) {

            Log.d("hello", "world");
        }
    return "done";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d(mTAG, "Inside onPostExecute");
    }


}
}
```